# I'm trying to align my text values next to my slider bar but having issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I've been working on this problem for a few hours now. (I'm terrible when it comes to CSS)

I have these two jQuery sliders with values. I'm trying to align "Rooms: 0" and "Bathrooms: 0" right next to their corresponding slider bar.

```
    .pricebox {
    width: 400px;
    margin:0px;
    height:50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.custom-slider {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}
.values {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
#cleared{
clear: both;
}


<div class="pricebox">
    <div id="slider-1" class="custom-slider"></div>
    <span>Rooms: <div id="slider-1-value" class="values">0</div></span>
<br />
    <div id="slider-2" class="custom-slider"></div>
    <span>Bathrooms: <div id="slider-2-value" class="values">0</div></span>
</div>
<div id="cleared">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your website and i have found the issue :
I have updated inline css in your div so make changes according to your style sheet then it will work :

Here is the code :

```
<div class="pricebox">
    <div class="custom-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="slider-1" aria-disabled="false" style="float: left;"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
    <span style="float: left;">Rooms: <div id="slider-1-value" style="display: inline;">1</div></span>
<br>
    <div class="custom-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="slider-2" aria-disabled="false" style="float: left;"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 20%;"></a></div>
    <span style="float: left;">Bathrooms: <div id="slider-2-value" style="display: inline;">2</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added your fix but it's still having alignment problems. Is the ui widget loading it's own css properties?

Comment: It was my browser cache, this solution worked. Thank you.